# Make SQL result have a class type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, datagridview

This is my first C# project, using VS 2008 and .NET 3.5, required by the client.

I have a List of type GradeVO

This is my connection and where I'm setting values to a DataGridView

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection Conexao = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=usr_mmidia; User ID=usr_mmidia; Password=123; MultipleActiveResultSets = true");
Conexao.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("MAG_SP_LISTA_SETORES_SQL", Conexao);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(("@p_codfil"), @"500"));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(("@p_categoria"), categoria));
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable t = new DataTable();
da.Fill(t);
dgNivel1.DataSource = t;
```

This code is working but I need the DataSource to receive a list of GradeVO, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you tied to using DataSets? If you use LINQ-to-SQL, it will handle the mapping of SQL to objects for you automatically. It's not considered great nowadays, but it's easy to get going and comes with the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could always do something like :

```
var myDataSource = t.Select(row => new GradeVO 
                                       {
                                           //your initialization logic here to get 
                                           //stuff from the row into the object
                                       });
dgNivel1.DataSource = myDataSource;
```